# Merging cells with page breaks, Excel not responding

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to merge together duplicate cells within selected columns of a spreadsheet, without having the merged cells go across page breaks so that it's readable after printing. So far what I have is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeSameCells()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

MergeCells:

For Each rng In Selection

    If rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" And rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PageBreak = -4142 Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        GoTo MergeCells
    End If

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

This results in VBA running indefinitely and Excel giving a Not Responding error. Is there a better way to do this to avoid these performance issues?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you intend to do... Can you better explain that? When the code does not run as expected it is completely wrong to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Having `Option Explicit` on top of the module and not declare `rng` variable, you should receive an error message, I think. Your code will  never stop in the way it is built. I suppose you start from one range selection and for each loop end, the code is sent outside to the `MergeCells:` label and start again doing that in an infinite loop...

Comment: In order to understand what happens, in such cases, you must run your code line by line (from IDE, pressing F8 for each code line) and observing what is happening on the sheet.

Comment: `If rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" ` should be `If rng.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" And rng.Value <> ""`

Comment: @FaneDuru The reason I was turning off Display Alerts is because of Excel's tendency to have a pop up letting you know it will take the top left value in the merge every time it loops through. I figured I was creating an infinite loop,  just wasnt sure what was causing it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are going wrong here:

1. As a general rule don't use `goto` statements outside of error handling (there are probably a few exceptions, but this isn't one of them).
2. Your `IF` is not doing what you specified in your question.

   `rng.Offset(1, 0).Value` is just trying to evaluate to true, so numbers and bools but not strings.

   `rng.value <> ""` is skipping empty strings, this can be an issue because a merged cell only takes the value from the top left most address, it will always skip the second merge if you have three rows that need to be merged together.

   You aren't comparing cell values at all in this.
3. That `IF` is likely to be true very often and with the `goto` will keep loop, getting you stuck in an infinite loop

Something like this is more in line with what you are looking for I believe:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngval As Variant
    Dim rowoffset As Integer
    rowoffset = 0
    For Each rng In Selection 'It's generally not the best practice to use selection
        rngval = rng.Value
        Do While rngval = "" 
        'This loop will just keep plowing backwards until it finds a non empty value within your selection. 
        'That gets you the last cell that has a value as merge destroys the values.
            rngval = rng.Offset(rowoffset, 0).Value
            rowoffset = rowoffset - 1
        Loop
        If rngval = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PageBreak = -4142 Then 
            Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        End If
        rowoffset = 0
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I'm still a bit of a novice with VBA but the explanations helped a lot